# stack/unstack/pivot dataframe on python/pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>  
Int64Index: 198300 entries, 0 to 198299  
Data columns (total 3 columns):  
var       198300  non-null values  
period    198300  non-null values  
value     141492  non-null values  
dtypes: float64(1), object(2)
```

I'd like to change i from having three collumns (var, period, value) to having all values of the period variable as columns, the values in var as rows.  i try using:

```
X.pivot(index='var', columns='period', values='value')
```

But I get this error:

```
    raise ReshapeError('Index contains duplicate entries, '
pandas.core.reshape.ReshapeError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape
```

But I've checked in excel, there are no duplicate entries...  Any help out there? Thanks

Comment: What do `X["var"].value_counts().head()` and `X["period"].value_counts().head()` show?

Comment: Turns out python is right, and i'm a douche, Found duplicates. Thanks!

Comment: The original poster even agrees that the question is unnecessary now.

Answer (score 0):

To give this question an answer: usually when `pandas` objects that there are duplicate entries, it's right.  To check this I often use

```
someseries.value_counts().head()
```

to see if one found its way in there.

Comment: I think that's wrong. `value_counts` is about the frequencies of the values of the series, not those of the indices. So if there are repeated index values, `value_counts` will not tell you.

Comment: @LuisE: the problem here came about when the OP was *pivoting*, and building an index from a `Series` column, which is why this worked.